# Cakephp images in the layout file not displaying when clicking a link with a parameter

Tags: html, cakephp, layout, hyperlink

i was confused and irritated a lot ...please help me to solve this problem 
Actually my problem is i have 2 layouts. one is default and one for registered users.
when i logged in as a registered user and when i try to click any link that passes a parameter and redirect to another page,then the layout file will not display any images.. i dont know exactly what is the problem. if i remove the parameter from the link and redirect to another page, then it will display all the images.

for example,

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['product_name'],array('controller'=>'products','action'=>'productMoreDetails',$product['Product']['id']));?>
```

when i click the above link the URL become

```
   http://localhost/meshopping/products/productMoreDetails/4
```

i think there is no wrong with the above code.but images are missing in the layout

[image: this is the part of layout file, here images are missing]

if anybody have any idea about this ..please reply me ..

Comment: Look for source and see if image tag has proper src path

Comment: @AngularAddict see , when i click a link that contain no parameter, then the images are showing...
the below code is works fine... but when i add a parameter then it shows the issue
<?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['product_name'],array('controller'=>'products','action'=>'productMoreDetails'));?>

Comment: Is the src correct in pagesource when images doesn't show up?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your link code. How are you outputting the images? Are you using the `Html::image` method?

Answer (score 3):

Image box shows up, but image isn't loading = wrong image src.

Try using CakePHP's `$this->Html->image()` - if you're using the standard of keeping your images in the `webroot/img/` folder, it should provide the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an image attached to a link, try this ...

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("products.gif"), array('controller'=>'products', 'action' => 'productMoreDetails'));
```

Comment: If you try this, you'll see it doesn't work.  Close, but needs the escape=>false part... but - this isn't the issue with the OP's code IMO - it's that he's using the wrong src.